# JAVA what causes end of stream on network sockets?

Tags: java, inputstream, objectinputstream, eofexception

From what I understand the whole point of `end of stream` is to tell the input stream when to stop reading data, which makes sense in file streams, but when it's an `ObjectInputStream` why would I want it to stop reading objects if I might send another one in the future.

In my case the `ObjectInputStream` throws an `EOFException` whenever it decides that something is causing the end of stream.

Code segment:

**Sending:**

```
public synchronized void sendCommand(CommandBase command){
    try {
        commandOutputStream.writeUnshared(command);
        commandOutputStream.flush();
        System.out.println("Sent " + command.getAction().toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to send " + command.getAction().toString());
        try {
            commandOutputStream.close();
            running = false;
            this.dispose();
            System.out.println("Closing command output stream");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Receiving**

```
while(going && tcpSender.running){
        //Get action from stream
        try {
            System.out.println("Available bytes: " + commandInputStream.available());
            Object command = ((CommandBase) commandInputStream.readObject());
            System.out.println("Action received");

            if (command instanceof CommandBase) {
                if(((CommandBase)command).getAction().equals(ActionType.MouseAction)){
                    System.out.println("Mouse action");
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Received Mouse Action");
                    ((MouseCommand)command).doAction(operator);
                }else if(((CommandBase)command).getAction().equals(ActionType.KeyboardAction)){
                    System.out.println("Keyboard action");
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Received Keyboard Action: " + ((KeyboardCommand)command).toString());
                    ((KeyboardCommand)command).doAction(operator);
                }else if(((CommandBase)command).getAction().equals(ActionType.CheckBooleanAction)){
                    System.out.println("Check boolean action");
                    udpSender.notifyThis((CheckBooleanCommand)command);
                }else{
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Received unknown command " + ((CommandBase)command).getAction().toString());
                    System.out.println("Action type is: " + ((CommandBase)command).getAction().toString());                         
                }
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            System.out.println("EOF-Exception - end of stream reached");
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO-Exception - Unable to read action \n Closing socket");
            try {
                commandInputStream.close();
                System.out.println("Closed command input stream");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            going = false;
            tcpSender.running = false;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class not found - failed to cast to Action");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

TL;DR: How does the `ObjectInputStream` decide that it's the end of a stream, and what causes it?
And how can I solve this problem?

Error message:

`

> java.io.EOFException at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please provide the responsible code. In concrete: Where are you sending/receiving data?

Comment: @L.Spillner I am sending data between 2 computers (usually on the same network), I can't provide all of the code because it's a part of a larger system and I don't think that it would work.

Comment: @L.Spillner I added the methods responsible for sending/receiving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the `ObjectInputStream` decide that it's the end of a stream

It happens when `ObjectInputStream` attempts to read from the underlying stream, and that stream returns `-1` ... which means that the end-of-stream has been reached.

> and what causes it?

In this case, the most likely explanation is that the remote end (the sender) has closed its socket, or it has crashed ... which will cause the socket to close.

(It is theoretically possible that the connection has been broken, but that is only likely to happen in obscure circumstances, so lets ignore that.)

> And how can I solve this problem?

You need to understand why the sending end has closed the socket.  Unfortunately, we cannot tell why that is because the code you have provided is not an MCVE.

Comment: I run a test and the sender side is still trying to send files to the receiver when it throws the `EOFException`, is there another possible solution?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that another thread is closing `commandOutputStream`?

Comment: It isn't that. Could it be that you can't send and receive on one sockets' input and output stream at the same time on different threads? Although I can't see why will that be the problem.

Comment: No.  It isn't that.   I suggest that you write an MCVE and add it to the question.  It is probably the **only way** we will be able to help you.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that bug in a freshly written example, so my guess it that i am missing something, if only i could send a link to the code :(

Comment: Going to try again, thanks for trying to help :) I really appreciate it

Comment: Nevermind, I checked it again and you were right, there was a reference to the same `ObjectOutputStream` in another class which I implemented as a "close on fail" mechanism, I just totally forgot about it :D